# do you lose an embassy/delegation if you go to war?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 6, do you lose your embassy/delegation with another nation if you go to war with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see more about Embassies/Delegations in detail on the [wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Diplomacy_(Civ6)).

In short to answer your question: Whether you denounce the other nation, or you go to war with them, delegations/embassies with that nation will be removed and will need to be resent upon improved relations/declaring peace. (Although it is much less likely they'll accept it, since they usually begin to hate you afterwards).